# Error while trying to put vector in text. [R-Markdown, R-Studio]

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I'm not getting the correct output from `$\vec{r}$`. Instead of the arrow on top of the r, I'm getting an arrow on the right.

Other specifications:

```
output:
  html_document
```

[image]

Comment: I think its a rendering problem. One hack would be to use `$\vec{\text{ }r}$`

Comment: It kinda works. The ouput is like an arrow over  ([blank space]+'r')

Comment: Yup like I said its a hack. Better than before i hope

Comment: I removed the [tag:rstudio] tag: even though you are using RStudio, the question has nothing to do with the IDE. Similarly, I removed the [tag:math] tag, since though you are representing a mathematical concept, I believe your question is about the rendering and representation, not about the math itself. If I'm wrong, my apologies.